# Writing an IIS rewrite rule for the Sitecore control panel URL

Tags: security, redirect

If I try to access `http://mydomain.com/sitecore` I get a 403 error.

I would instead prefer for IIS to automatically redirect to `https://mydomain.com/sitecore`.

I added the following rule in `RewriteRules.config`:

```
<rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS - Staging Knowledge Sitecore" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)mydomain/sitecore"/>
    <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mydomain.com/sitecore" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

But this doesn't work - `http://mydomain.com/sitecore` still returns 403.

**QUESTION**

How do I implement a redirect to HTTPS?

EDIT: the following rule is successfully redirecting the base domain, that is, from `http://mydomain.com` to `https://mydomain.com`:

```
<rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS - Staging URL" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)"/>
    <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomain.com"/>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: 403 is a security error, not a redirect error.  Maybe you have IP locking on the site?

Comment: @Emanuele Ciriachi might be a copy/paste error, but looks like your match URL is missing the .com .  Did you want to only be redirecting to HTTPS for that specific URL? Or everything on that host?

Comment: @GeorgeTucker It was a copy/paste error indeed. I only need to redirect for that specific URL - I have another rule for the base domain that works. Everything on that host would be ideal.

Comment: @RichardHauer I edited the question - I have another rule that successfully HTTPS-redirects the base domain.

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi - Could it be that you have a Netscalar LB which is returning the 403 response ?

Comment: @AbhayDhar The instance is stored in an AWS virtual machine; I'm not familiar with Netscalar, but we don't have multiple instances for CM/CD - it's a small operation.

Comment: and just to be clear there is a 403 response without the IIS rewrite rule in place

Comment: Yes, I get a 403 response without such rules.

Comment: @EmanueleCiriachi In your `match` (the broken one) you should have the `url="sitecore.*"` - that is, remove the `mydomain/` bit .  Host names travel in a header, the URL is only the path (without the leading slash) and doesn't include the query string either.  The basic structure of the rule seems OK though.  It's not obvious why you would get a 403, however, as this is a security failure and not anything to do with HTTP/S normally

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a rule with `type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403"`. So, try placing below rule before `CustomResponse` rule.

**Updated Rule** -

```
<rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS - Staging Knowledge Sitecore" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)sitecore"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mydomain.com/sitecore" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, sorry.

Comment: Are you still getting 403 error after adding this rule?

Comment: also, do you have a rule for CustomResponse code 403?

Comment: Yes. I enter `http://mydomain.com/sitecore` and this results in a 403. No, I do not have a CustomResponse.

Comment: can you share all existing rules?

Comment: I tried moving the relevant ones at the top of the list - rules are evaluated top to bottom, so sharing the rest would not help.

Comment: This did not work, sorry. I tried removing every other rule and only leaving the one you suggested, and it didn't work.

Comment: I tested it on local IIS before posting it here and for 403, I had to add another rule manually to simulate same behaviour. In your case you need to first figure out the reason for 403 error.